# how do i change button/image onclick to active state?

Tags: html, css, image

Here is what i want:
[image: Example]

Now in more detail:

I have 2 iframes, one on top of the other. the one above has 4 buttons/images, the one below is where a url/link will be displayed when one of these buttons/images gets clicked. i got this working...

what i want now is to have those buttons change image from inactive (ie. light pink) to active (ie. red) state when they are clicked. also, when i click on another of the 4 buttons it will turn red and the previous active (red) button/image must turn back to its inactive state (light pink). so i want 2 images here: (1) active.png and (2) inactive.png.

ALSO, i want the buttons to change to active.png when i hover over them. this i was able to manage with onmouseover and onmouseout effect. its just the ACTIVE part is what i cant figure out.

do i need javascript or can i do without it in case some user has it disabled?

i was also thinking about maybe using radio buttons and then skinning them with my active.png and inactive.png using css or something, but i dont know how to do this either :P  i dont know what is the best and simplest way to go?

------------UPDATE-----------

ok i got something working but im not all the way there yet. it might not even be the way to go, but what i've done is create 4 links and given them all an id (ie.button1, button2..)

then in css i did this for each:

button1 { width: 66px; height: 70px; display: block; background-image:url(images/inactive1.png); } 
button1:hover { width: 66px; height: 70px; display: block; background-image:url(images/active1.png); } 
button1:focus{ width: 66px; height: 70px; display: block; background-image:url(images/active1.png); }

but i dont want it to loose focus unless another one of the buttons is clicked. cuz now its loosing focus if i click anywhere on the page :(   how can i fix this?

Comment: What have you tried already? You can't do this with HTML & CSS alone unless you're creating 4 different static pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made these two files that cover all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Deep East Music</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .buttons { float:left; width:60px; height:25px; margin:10px 0 0 5px; cursor:pointer; }
        .buttons[isselected = "true"] { background-color:#ff7373; }
        .buttons[isselected = "false"] { background-color:#cccccc; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button1").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");

                $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F38593173");
            });

            $("#button2").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F37674430");

                ////Use one of these if you need to reload the iframe
                //$('#myiframe').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
                //$("#myiframe").attr("src", $("#myiframe").attr("src"));
            });

            $("#button3").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F3442336");
            });

            $("#button4").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F38359257");
            });

        });


        function ClickedButton1 () {
            $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F38593173");
            return false;
        };

        function ClickedButton2 () {
            $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F37674430");
            return false;
        };

        function ClickedButton3 () {
            $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F3442336");
            return false;
        };

        function ClickedButton4 () {
            $("#myiframe").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F38359257");
            return false;
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div id="button1" class="buttons" isselected="true">button1</div>
        <div id="button2" class="buttons" isselected="false">button2</div>
        <div id="button3" class="buttons" isselected="false">button3</div>
        <div id="button4" class="buttons" isselected="false">button4</div>

        <iframe id="mybuttonsiframe" width="100%" height="60" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="buttons.htm"></iframe>

        <iframe id="myiframe" width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F38593173"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And buttons.htm looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Deep East Music</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* CSS Here */
        .iframebuttons { float:left; width:100px; height:25px; margin:10px 0 0 5px; cursor:pointer; }
        .iframebuttons[isselected = "true"] { background-color:#ff7373; }
        .iframebuttons[isselected = "false"] { background-color:#cccccc; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#iframebutton1").click(function () {
                $(".iframebuttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                parent.ClickedButton1();
            });

            $("#iframebutton2").click(function () {
                $(".iframebuttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                parent.ClickedButton2();
            });

            $("#iframebutton3").click(function () {
                $(".iframebuttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                parent.ClickedButton3();
            });

            $("#iframebutton4").click(function () {
                $(".iframebuttons").attr("isselected", "false");
                $(this).attr("isselected", "true");
                parent.ClickedButton4();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="button" id="iframebutton1" class="iframebuttons" isselected="true" value="iframebutton1" />
        <input type="button" id="iframebutton2" class="iframebuttons" isselected="false" value="iframebutton2" />
        <input type="button" id="iframebutton3" class="iframebuttons" isselected="false" value="iframebutton3" />
        <input type="button" id="iframebutton4" class="iframebuttons" isselected="false" value="iframebutton4" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without JS, is to create four static pages as mentioned in the comment to your original post.

Your body markup would look like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="site1.htm"></a></li>
    <li><a href="site2.htm"></a></li>
    <li><a href="site3.htm"></a></li>
    <li><a href="site4.htm"></a></li>
</ul>
<iframe src="www.url.com">
</iframe>
```

The list above is your Navigation. You do not need a separate `iframe`, since you have four static pages. In each static page, the `li`-element containing the link to the active static page gets a class called "active".

The `iframe` stores the url, you want to be displayed in there.

In your css file, you can style your navigation like that:

```
#nav a {background: url('images/inactive.png');}

#nav a:hover,
#nav li.active a{
    background: url('images/active1.png');
}
```

This should work, but a solution using JS would be much more elegant.