# How to change image button image while active using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change **image1.png** while `<a>` tag is **active**.

```
<a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="2" class="img-responsive">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: will you please add some more explanation? which tag is active and which new image do you want to change?

Comment: I think you should do it through javascript onclick event.


<a href="#" onclick="this.firstChild.src='image2.png'"><img src="image1.png" id="2" class="img-responsive" >Click Here</a>

Comment: Why you don't want to do it through javascript on JQuery? Reasons?

Comment: Are you looking for toggling image in button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i change button/image onclick to active state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372354/how-do-i-change-button-image-onclick-to-active-state)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css selector :active

for example the html part

```
<a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="2" class="img-responsive">Click Here</a>
```

and the css

```
.img-responsive {
     background-image: url("image1.png");
}
.img-responsive:active{
    background-image: url("image2.png");         
}
```

Comment: Don't want to change background image, please suggest to change image src,
with different css class

Comment: i am trying this way in css.. but not working in IE and Firefox:


img:active {
     content:url(".image2.png");
            }

Comment: @AmitKArya, this won't work in IE and fireforx as this is CSS3 and not compatible with IE < 9 version. Use jQuery or Javacript for changing image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="2" class="img-responsive">Click Here</a>
<script>
    $('img').click(function(){
       $(this).attr('src','image2.png').addClass('active');
     })
 </script>
```

Comment: i am trying this way in css.. but not working in IE and Firefox:

img:active {
     content:url(".image2.png");
            }